# How to fix chrome rendering/jarring animation issue?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

THis is a drawer opens from the hnav - I am using slidedown function in jquery

> $(".hnavDrawerWr").slideDown(function(){

and also as someone suggested, I also included

> -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

but I still get this effect using chrome browser.

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try quitting chrome, it could be chrome.

Otherwise try [web animation](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/web-animations.html)s and animate the height.

```
var player = document.timeline.play(new Animation(document.querySelector('.hnavDrawerWr', [
        {transform: "scaleY(0)"},
        {transform: "scaleY(1)"}
    ]
));
```